# createTable() generates drop table

Tags: knex.js

knex v0.7.6, pg v4.3.0

Can anyone explain why a knex dropTable() followed by a createTable() is resulting in generation of two drop tables?  The second sql "drop table" is generated on call to createTable()

Code

```
  return schema.dropTable('users')
    .then(function(){
      return schema.createTable('users',function(t){
        t.string('login').primary();
        t.json('data',true);});
    })
```

Knex debug output

```
    Table
{ __cid: '__cid1', sql: 'drop table "mytable"', bindings: [] }
{ __cid: '__cid2', sql: 'drop table "mytable"', bindings: [] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to go read this online but try this:

```
return knex.schema.dropTable(TableName).then(function(exists) {
  if (!exists) {
    return knex.schema.createTable(TableName, function(t) {
        t.string('login').primary().unique();
        t.json('data',true);});
    });
  }
});
```

I am not sure what `model.table` is. but if you want, try replacing `TableName` with `model.table`.

Comment: Not sure how this is working for you.  In my testing this simply avoids making the createTable() call as the dropTable() always succeeds and the _then_ param contains a results object.